# Fetch public photo sources from my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch the public photos I've posted on my facebook page.
With that, I plan to make a caroussel on my website that displays the photos I posted on my facebook page.

Using the facebook Graph API, I ended up with this:

```
my-page?fields=albums.fields(photos.fields(source))
```

The thing is that the response I get is:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "DxhgQ12ym3r"
  }
}`

I've tried to get the app reviewed, but at certain point they ask me to attach a video in which I show how the final user will use the app. But this is a server-to-server app, so I don't understand how am I supposed to answer that petition.

I've also tried to get a page access token, but I get the following error:

> Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I'm quite lost, if anyone could guide me a bit or explain me step by step how to reach my goal...

Comment: Page token is the way to go; but you will only be able to grant that permission to your app in live mode – if you get your app reviewed before. You can leave it in dev mode, then anyone with a role in the app should be able to grant this permission - but rate limits are stricter for dev apps.

Comment: As for how to submit a server-to-server app for review, there’s a dedicated chapter in the docs about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps